# latlang is not defined and no response from AJAX IN Google maps

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-maps

Errors:
`latlng is undefined(var lng = latlng.lng(); )` Although it gets a value and put in textboxes
no response from ajax. I want response as text, not xml. What I am missing?

```
function load() {
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
//map.addControl(new GMap2TypeControl());
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(centerLatitude, centerLongitude), startZoom);

GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latlng) {
var inputForm = document.createElement("form");
inputForm.setAttribute("action","");
inputForm.onsubmit = function() {storeMarker(); return false;};
//retrieve the longitude and lattitude of the click point
var lng = latlng.lng();
var lat = latlng.lat();
inputForm.innerHTML = '<fieldset style="width:150px;">'
+ '<legend><b>Add Property<b></legend>'
+ '<label for="name"><B>Name</b></label>'
+ '<input type="text" id="name" style="width:100%;"/>'
+ '<label for="address"><b>Address</b></label>'
+ '<input type="text" id="address" style="width:100%;"/>'
+ '<label for="address"><b>Type</b></label>'
+'<select id="type"><option>Homes</option><option>Plots</option><option>Commercials</option></select>'
+ '<label for="address"><b>Prperty Type</b></label>'
+'<select id="property_type"><option>Sale</option><option>Rent</option><option>Wanted</option></select>'
+ '<label for="address"><b>Descreption</b></label>'
+ '<textarea id="description" cols="15" rows="4" name="description"></textarea>'
+ '<input type="text" id="longitude" value="' + lng + '"/>'
+ '<input type="text" id="latitude" value="' + lat + '"/>'
+ '<input type="submit" value="ADD"/>'
+ '</fieldset>';

map.openInfoWindow (latlng,inputForm);
});
}
}
```

Here is the store marker function:

```
function storeMarker(){
//alert("xainee");
var lng = document.getElementById("longitude").value; //getting the longitude
var lat = document.getElementById("latitude").value;//getting the latitude

alert(lng +"and"+lat);
//geeting the user data in form
var getVars =  "storeMarker.php?name=" + document.getElementById("name").value
+ "&address=" + document.getElementById("address").value
+ "&description=" + document.getElementById("description").value
+ "&property_type=" + document.getElementById("property_type").value
+ "&type=" + document.getElementById("type").value
+ "&lng=" + lng
+ "&lat=" + lat ;

//alert(getVars);
//////////////////////////////////////////
var Request = false;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  Request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 if (Request) {
     alert("workinh");
     Request.open("GET","storeMarker.php"+getVars,true);

     Request.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (Request.readyState==4 && Request.status==200)
    {
    document.write(responseText);
    }
  }
   Request.send(null);
}

}
```

And here is the `storeMarker.php` page:

```
<?php
include_once('clsGeneral.php');
echo $name=$_GET['name'];
echo $address=$_GET['address'];
echo $type=$_GET['type'];
echo $property_type=$_GET['property_type'];
echo $descreption=$_GET['description'];
echo $lat=(float)$_GET['lat'];
echo $lan=(float)$_GET['lng'];

$my_query="INSERT INTO map_marker SET name='$name',
    address='$address',type='$type',property_address='$property_type',
    descreption='$descreption',lat='$lat',lan='$lat'";
db_execute($my_query);
?>
```

My problem is that when `Geventlistner` is fired through click so popup is rendered showing all elements with latitude and longitude values in textboxes but when I click in any textbox it shows an error "latlan is not defined". Second it's not sending the request and for instance it send than no response in here I want response in string not in XML.

Comment: You also appear to be asking multiple questions at the same time here (one is a Google Maps API question, the other is a seemingly-unrelated AJAX question).  StackOverflow works best if you ask each of those questions separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the fine Google Maps manual](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/events.html#Event_Listeners):

> Many events in the Maps API event system pass arguments when the event is triggered. For example, the `GMap2` "click" event passes an `overlay` and `overlaylatlng` **if the map click occurs on an overlay**; otherwise, it passes a `latlng` of the map coordinate. You can access these arguments by passing the specified symbols directly to the functions within the event listeners.
>
> In the example below, we **first test to ensure the click was on a map tile by checking if the `latlng` argument is defined**; if so, we open an info window above the clicked coordinate and display the coordinate converted to pixel space along with the zoom level.

Comment: SIR! i am not getting wt u r talking about??plz let me know in my code,how to change in my code to get what i want

Comment: @Xainee Khan: I don't know how to say it any more clearly than Google says it.  When you get a `click` event, the `latlng` argument may be **undefined**.  You will need to handle that case.  The page I linked to shows an example of how to do this.  Are you expecting me to write your code for you?

Comment: no no need to write a code i just wanted to mention it thanx BTW

Comment: hey wts wrong with my storemarker() its not sending     'Request.open("GET","storeMarker.php"+getVars,true);'               .the getVars is not accessible there in storemarker.php page and when ajax is called so it make busy my browser do u have any idea??help plz

Comment: @Xainee Khan: Please post your follow-up question as a new question instead of asking in a comment.